# Connect multiple Messenger ChatBot on Single Facebook App

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm managing a Facebook page and Have a Facebook validated Node.js ChatBot on it. It works fine and now I would like to know how to duplicate this ChatBot on multiple other Facebook pages. A single App, a single ChatBot and multiple Facebook pages linked on it.

For doing that, If I understood, I have to:
**- Collect the page.id :**

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body

    // Make sure this is a page subscription
   if (data.object === 'page') {
       // Iterate over each entry
       data.entry.forEach((pageEntry) => {
           // get the pageId
           const pageId = pageEntry.id
           ...
```

**- Maintain an object mapping page ids to the access token associated with each page id:**

```
const accessTokens = {
    myPageId1: 'myPageAccessToken1',
    myPageId2: 'myPageAccessToken2',
}
```

**- Then when sending the response, just specify the corresponding page access_token:**

```
const callSendAPI = (pageId, messageData) =>
    rp({
        uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messages',
        qs: { access_token: accessTokens[pageId] },
        method: 'POST',
        body: messageData,
        json: true,
     })
```

Now I only want to know how to ask user permission to manage all their pages and let them subscribe to my app with the Facebook page of their choice.

**Can you please explain me more about this procedure please? My goal is to create a platform in which a user can choose among all this Facebook Page and connect my App to his page (like Chatfuel and other platform).**

Comment: Your app secret belongs to your app id ... and if your app id is the only one that’s going to be used here, then you _know_ the secret already.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, I will EDIT my question but can you tell me more about the procedure to ask user permission to control pages and subscribe pages to my App ! How can I do that ?

Comment: That is all in the documentation ... asking users for the necessary permissions is done by implementing Facebook Login; and how to subscribe a page to your bot is mentioned in the Messenger platform documentation as well.

Comment: An app can only be subscribed to the webhook events for one page. So you can have one bot that handles the events from multiple pages.

Comment: @amuramoto I don't understand what you said ... can please be more specific ?

Comment: @PabloDelaNoche Sure. You said you want "A single App, a single ChatBot and multiple Facebook pages linked on it." But this is not possible. For the Messenger Platform, each app can only subscribe to receive the webhook events from one page. A single bot can be set up to handle webhook events for multiple apps.

So in the scenario you're describing, each customer would have a separate app that is subscribed to their page. And each of those apps would have the same webhook URI set, which points to your one bot.

Comment: @amuramoto Are you sure ? Because I can subscribe manually from developers.facebook.com to multiples pages from the webhook section so that's why I don't understand your answer !

Comment: Sorry, you're correct about that.