# I can use multiple Facebook messenger connecting to the same agent of DialogFlow?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es

I have a Facebook Messenger connected to an agent of DialogFlow, but I need connect more Facebook Messengers to the same agent.

I need do this, because I need allow to all of our clients to integrate her self Facebook Messenger with the agent that I have configured.

Otherwise, I would need to modify and update each agent for each Facebook Messenger.

Is there any way to do this?

Regards,
Andrés Gilabert

Comment: Yes you can do this but by programming i can explain you if you want in nodejs javascript

Comment: Thanks Manjeet, can you explain how I can do this in Nodejs?

Comment: Please refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770548/connect-multiple-messenger-chatbot-on-single-facebook-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770548/connect-multiple-messenger-chatbot-on-single-facebook-app)